# как в ListView поменять цвет (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Задача: необходимо использовать для каждой четной и нечетной строки свою цветовую схему (максимум 2 цвета для любого числа записей).
Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Очень просто. Используйте `AlternationIndex` и триггеры:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="..." AlternationCount="2">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Получается:

[image: alternation count]